# Managing many pages on a WordPress website

Tags: pages

I've got a WordPress site I'm working on with over 500 pages.

We need to rearrange many pages at once but the existing Plugins I've seen really struggle with this many Pages. They either don't allow you to move multiple Pages at once, or you can't move Pages after you do a Search or they're very slow.

Does anyone know of anything better?

Comment: WP CSV provides a really nice method for exporting pages to CSV.  It becomes a quicker process to make bulk edits this way before importing the pages again with WP CSV.

Comment: Not so quick when you've got over 500 pages with associated content - that's one massive spreadsheet.

Comment: Agreed!  Ergo "...a quicker process...".   I imagine nothing is quick with 500+ pages.  Good luck.

Comment: What do you mean by re-arrange? Changing parent and children pages? Setting menu order? Dates?

Comment: I'd like to move several hundred pages to a new Parent.

Comment: If you can tell which they are (or if they have a parent in common) and it's a one time thing, I would write a SQL query to do it and do it directly in the database.